# Dynamics CRM 2016 on-prem: Unable to access organizations using Plugin Registration Tools

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to connect to Dynamics CRM 2016 on-prem environment using plugin registration tool. I can surf the url in browser but I am unable to connect using plugin registration tool.

I would like to seek kind advice from the experts. Following is the exception thrown by the plugin registration tool.

```
Source  : Not Provided
Method  : Not Provided
Date    : 6/2/2016
Time    : 11:58:01
Error   : You don't have permission to access any of the organizations on the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server that you specified. Check with your CRM administrator.
Parameter name: dev-crm.test.com
Stack Trace : Not Provided
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try to sghin with user that not have permmistion 
try to sighn with the admin user